# How to bind multiple keys to different functions using pyHook in Python?

Tags: python, class, keypress, pyhook

I'm trying to get my program to execute two functions called "pauseinit" and "startinit" using different keypresses that can be detected even when a python GUI isn't the focus.
My code reads:

```
class Keystroke_Watcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hm = HookManager()
        self.hm.KeyDown = self.on_keyboard_event
        self.hm.HookKeyboard()


    def on_keyboard_event(self, event):
        try:
            if event.KeyID  == 35: #End key
                self.pauseinit()
        finally:
            return True
        try:
            if event.KeyID == 36: #Home key
                self.startinit()
        finally:
            return True

        def pauseinit(self):
            print "pausing"

        def startinit(self):
            print "starting"

        def shutdown(self):
            PostQuitMessage(0)
            self.hm.UnhookKeyboard()

watcher = Keystroke_Watcher()
PumpMessages()
```

The "pauseinit" function works fine and prints "pausing" to the console but "startint" doesn't register at all apon pressing the Home key. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'm just dumb. For anyone who didn't think through it like I did, I just put the second 'if' into the 'try'.

```
    def on_keyboard_event(self, event):
    try:
        if event.KeyID  == 35:
            self.pauseinit()

        if event.KeyID == 36:
            self.startinit()
    finally:
        return True
```